# What are the different ways of calling a component in JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I call/invoke a component in jsx like so:

```
function arrow(){
  return ( 
    <div>Cool arrow</div>
  )
}

return (
  <div className="container">
      {arrow()}
  </div>  
)
```

VS

```
const Arrow = () => {
  return ( 
    <div>Cool arrow<div>
  )
}

return (
  <div className="container">
      <Arrow />
  </div>  
)
```

Are there any differences to be aware of? They are both components in the same file but I have noticed state behaves differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are differences

> ```
> function arrow(){
>   return ( 
>     <div>Cool arrow</div>
>   )
> }
>
> return (
>   <div className="container">
>     {arrow()}
>   </div>  
> )
> ```

Here `arrow` is ***not*** a React component, it is simply a function that returns some JSX. Because `arrow` is a function and not a React component it won't and can't have state or any lifecycle. The function is called each render and JSX computed and returned.

> ```
> const Arrow = () => {
>   return ( 
>     <div>Cool arrow<div>
>   )
> }
>
> return (
>   <div className="container">
>     <Arrow />
>   </div>  
> )
> ```

Here `Arrow` ***is*** a React component. Use caution where you define it though. If you define `Arrow` within another React component then it will be recreated each time the outer component renders. `Arrow` would be remounted each render of the outer component, and thus may have some unintended side-effects because of this. If you do this, be sure to declare `Arrow` ***outside*** any other components.

> They are both component's in the same file but I have noticed state
> behaves differently?

I don't see any state used in either snippet so it's difficult to address this question, but I imagine any state issues may be related to the re-declaration/re-mounting issue described above. New component === new initial state when mounting.

> What are the different ways of calling a component in JSX?

You don't call React components directly, you template them in JSX and React handles converting the JSX to callable functions and maintains the component lifecycle.